# Invalidate cache on a REST endpoint

Tags: 8, caching

I have an endpoint that returns an array of Order entities, but it's caching the results so when a new order is placed the cache has to be cleared.

The code within the endpoint is:

```
// Tried this also.
// $this->orderManager->resetCache()
$orders = $this->orderManager->loadByProperties([
  'uid' => $this->customer->id(),
]);
$response = new ResourceResponse($orders);
// maybe this doesn't work because it's an \Drupal\Entity\commerce\Order[]
$response->addCacheableDependency($orders);

return new ResourceResponse($orders);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried looping over the orders and adding the dependency for each individually?

Comment: Had not tried that, thanks.  Combined with 4k4's answer I'm all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comment from @Clive, you can only add single objects as dependency. But you need to add a list tag as well, because the entity query may change because of entities added or modified that are not in the cached list.

```
$list_tags = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('entity_type')->getListCacheTags();
$response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheTags($list_tags);
```

Comment: Once combined with the loop this works great - thanks (again)!